# Adding Data in Entities with the Relationship

Tags: ios, database, core-data, entity-relationship, iphonecoredatarecipes

[image]

In My Model of Core Data , I have such relationship (See Photo)

Now

```
Location *locObj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Location"
                                                              inManagedObjectContext [self managedObjectContext]];

Room *roomObj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Room"    
                                       inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
```

I have declare this two entities like this .

Questions :-

1. As I have declared object of Room and Location , First I need to fill
   the data of location and then I need to fill the data of Room and
   then I need to Add room in the location method?Is that correct ?
2. What If I have the big data ? every time do I need to add objects or is there any custom supported class which we can connect ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer

1. The order is not important here, but reference to other entity object. You can just use the code

   ```
   [locObj addWithRoomObject:roomObj];
   roomObj.withLocation = locObj;
   ```
2. There is no such custom supported class. You can just use auto generated accessors in core data and it will automatically handle. You can call the function:

   ```
   [locObj addWithRoomObject:roomObj];
   ```

**UPDATE**

To add more rooms:

```
Location *locObj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Location"
                                                          inManagedObjectContext [self managedObjectContext]];

locObj.locationName = LOCATION_NAME;

Room *room1 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Room"    
                                   inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
// Fill room1 details
...
room1.withLocation = locObj;
[locObj addWithRoomObject:room1];

Room *room2 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Room"    
                                   inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
// Fill room2 details
...
room2.withLocation = locObj;
[locObj addWithRoomObject:room2];

// so on..
```

Comment: How can I add one->many connection here ? How can I add more than two rooms in the same location ?